# Normalization - Understanding Concept

Tags: ms-access, database-design

At an introductory level, is there a simple way to understand normalization to 3NF? To attempt to explain my confusion, I have an example table that has affiliated political party codes along with description, description of being congressman or senator along with codes for each, names of 4 individuals, and 4 examples of a bill voted on and yes or no of individuals vote. Each has date of voted and I have to allow for additional entry of various bills in future tobe voted on. I have to enforce referential integrity. I am not asking for the answer, but when attempting to normalize,  do I have to enforce integrity on each table? I am missing something to understanding how to normalize tables to 3NF.

Comment: 3NF: "[Every] non-key [attribute] must provide a fact about the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key... so help me Codd".

If you take a stab at what you think is a good design, people might be able to help you better than from your problem-statement.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Do not have access to all details to my original post since it was a hw assignment for an online class. Another example I do have is a real estate ofc, property details, property may have more than one owner, one owner may have 1+ property. County(County[PK],CountyRatePerAcre), Owner(TaxId[PK],OwnerName)Property(Lot[PK],AreaInAcres,Price,TotalTax),Town(Town[PK,TownRatePerAcre)

Comment: I apologize for my multiple posts, etc. This is my first time attempting to interact on this site.